# RGBa border color & <input> element

Tags: html, css, rgba

I ran into an issue while working on a webdesign, trying to apply a semi-transparent (RGBa) border color to  elements doesn't seem to work properly. You get a non-transparent border instead. Here's a CSS sample:

```
header > div form {
    width: 229px;
    background: url('img/connexion.png') no-repeat;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    text-align: center;
}

header > div form > p:first-child {
    color: #1B2E83;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin-top: 31px;
}

header > div form input[type=email], header > div form input[type=text], header > div form input[type=password] {
    width: 140px;
    height: 20px;
    border: 2px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.14);
}
```

Expected behavior: a gray, transparent border. I tried it on another element on the same page and it works perfectly.

Actual behavior: A gray border. That is all. RGBa values seem to be somewhat interpreted as the color given is black and the result is gray, it just ain't transparent at all though.

Tested on: Firefox 8.0, Chrome 16.0.912.63

Since it happens on both Webkit & Gecko, maybe there's something I'm doing wrong... I tried to remove position: absolute on the container, to remove the background image (which is a PNG with transparency)... nothing changed.

Comment: Could you build a test case on http://jsfiddle.net so we can test it on our machines?

Comment: Sure : http://jsfiddle.net/VT4ye/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem appears to be that an `input` element is a replaced element (in that it's supplied/rendered by the underlying OS, not the browser itself; though I don't know the OS can't handle the `rgba()` color properly).

It's not an ideal solution, but wrapping the `input` elements in another element, and styling the borders of the wrapping element works:

```
<form method="post">
    <p>Espace connexion</p>
    <div>
    <input type="email" name="mail" placeholder="Votre adresse e-mail" required="required" value="" />
    </div>
    <div>
    <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Votre mot de passe" required="required" pattern=".{4,}" title="4 caractères minimum" />
    </div>
    <input type="submit" value="OK" />
</form>
```

With the CSS:

```
form div, div#test {
    width: 140px;
    height: 20px;
    border: 20px solid rgba(255,0,0,0.5);
}

form div input {
    width: 100%; /* to stop the inputs being wider than the containg div */
    box-sizing: border-box; /* to include the border as part of the width */
}
```

[Updated JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/VT4ye/11/).

Comment: That's probably the only solution. Though I would do it with JavaScript to prevent my markup from being icky.

Comment: Both are unsatisfying solutions to me... I really hope Mozilla & Chromium teams are going to work on that one.

Anyway, thank you for your time =)

Comment: Don't worry, I'm definitely going to use it since it's the only possibility =) I just meant it's a shame you can't do it without extra markup. Thank you again for the help !

Answer (score 0):

You can add:

```css
input {
  background-clip: padding-box;
  border: 2px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.14);
}
```

for work rgba in input.

https://css-tricks.com/transparent-borders-with-background-clip/